# Flutter Scroll awareness

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

I want to figure out if the user is **near** the edge of the screen and show/hide a FAB based on that. I tried it using `scrollController.position.pixels` but that's unreliable on devices with different size.

After that, I tried using `maxScrollExtent`:

```dart
_scroller.position.pixels > _scroller.position.maxScrollExtent - 200 || _scroller.position.pixels > _scroller.position.minScrollExtent + 200
? setState(() => _showButton = true)
: setState(() => _showButton = false);
```

That's no help as well.

Also, is there any way to detect fast scrolls vs slow scrolls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition:

```dart
(_scroller.position.maxScrollExtent - offset < 200) || (offset - _scroller.position.minScrollExtent < 200) 
    ? _showButton = true 
    : _showButton = false;
```

You can detect fast and slow scrolls based on the velocity:

```dart
_scroller.position.activity.velocity
```

Comment: And what would be offset here?

Comment: That's `_scroller.offset`.